# How to configure eclipse to pick config file?

Tags: java, spring-boot, eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I am using eclipse for spring boot development. In my project, the environment configuration file is inside in the config folder in resources folder. But when I run eclipse it is not picking the files.

As per spring documentation, the configuration files can be in config folder.

[image]

- **Eclipse version:** 2022-06 (4.24.0)
- **Spring boot version:** 2.6.8
- **working:** project/src/main/resources/application-test.yaml
- **not working:** project/src/main/resources/config/application-test.yaml
- **not working:** project/src/main/resources/config/some-other-config.yaml

could you please suggest how to make eclipse support this one?

Comment: Did you do a rebuild?

Comment: can you also  provide details of your target folder (assuming you are using maven)  or build output

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Yes, I tried that... but didn't help

Comment: @ShaileshChandra it is having 

`target
 generated-sources
  annotations
 generated-test-sources
  test-annotations
 maven-status
  maven-compiler-plugin`

Comment: and you can see the config directory in target/classes/config?

Comment: I don't see the target/classes folder

Comment: I think you don’t have a JDK configured for your eclipse

Comment: I had already configured JDK in window->preferences->Java->installed JREs... do you mean the same or something else?

Comment: is your problem solved with below answer, I upvoted it, as I think it fits your problem

Answer (score 2):

I tried this myself with a simple Spring Boot project inside of Spring Tools 4 on Eclipse and the underlying mechanism of Spring Boot seems to work fine.

The config file is picked up from `src/main/resources` as well as `src/main/resources/config`. But you have to keep in mind that Spring Boot maps the identifier that you have in the name behind the `application-` to the active profiles. So the file `application-test.yml` will only be taken into account when you have the setting `spring.profiles.active=test` active (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.files.profile-specific). This allows you to have multiple property files for various environments around.

In case you have a totally different name for your config file, you need to specify that via `spring.config.name`.

More details can be found here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.files